# Why TabContainer doesnot show?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

> I had my **TabContainer** but when I run the **TabContainer** didn't display .

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TC_Article" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="100%"
        Visible="true">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="Add" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Add New</HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="gridpading" id="div" runat="server">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;"
                        runat="server" visible="False">
                        <tr id="tr_body" runat="server" visible="False">
                            <td align="left" width="150px" class="CDtxt" runat="server">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Body" runat="server" Text="Article_Body"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left" class="CDtxt" runat="server">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <cc1:Editor ID="Ed_Body" runat="server"  Height="340px" Width="100%" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 194px" runat="server">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
    </asp:TabContainer>
```

> I added the Register

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Comment: Is this showing any error. Have u added script manager in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in Register tag in Namespace and also add script manager in page. Try this.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Comment: it solved the Tabcontainer issue but editor it is the problem as when I added the editor it created this <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
    TagPrefix="cc2" %>

Comment: Is still there any problem. If not then Please tick my answer right and vote it.

Comment: yes there is aproblem with editor register <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc2" %>

Comment: For html editor u don't need to Add .HTML Editor. Only Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" will work.